Opening more than one KML in a single Google Earth instance from the Linux command line
I’m trying to display the motion of an object in Google Earth. I get live [Lat, Lon, Alt] information. I have a C++ program that polls it, and automatically appends the information as a Placemark inside a single .kml file.
I actually have a working program in Windows, where inside a while() loop iterating over time, I use a thread which runs the system() command in the following manner:
std::system(KML_NAME.c_str());
By working, I mean that every time I execute the line above, the same Google Earth instance would reload my KML file, run over the existing one (which has the same name), display the newly appended file, thus displaying motion.
I now have to port to Linux, specifically Linux Mint 21.1 Vera (Ubuntu / Debian based).
I added a line removing Google Earth’s instance-running-lock:
std::string COMMAND1 = "rm ~/.googleearth/instance-running-lock";
std::system(COMMAND1.c_str());

I would then run the command:
std::string COMMAND2 = "google-earth-pro " + KML + " &";
std::system(COMMAND2.c_str());

Issue: Even with instance-running-lock deleted, after the first execution of COMMAND2, meaning after opening the first KML file, upon the second time Google Earth would attempt to open the second KML file in a new instance. This is illegal in Earth, because rightfully only one instance should run, so it fails and an error window would show up:

Google Earth Crash Detected - Google Earth may not have started up or shut down correctly when last run. Would you like to launch the Repair Tool, or attempt to continue starting Google Earth?

I need to be able to automatically open several KML files under Temporary Places in the same Earth instance, from the command line. I tried going through the Google Earth directory on my machine in order to see if I can configure some file/s on my behalf, but I didn’t find a solution. google-earth-pro is a symbolic link to the executable shell script googleearth which does some initialization and then calls the binary googleearth-bin which runs Earth.
I searched the web and came across 3 posts of the same issue:
https://groups.google.com/g/kml-support-getting-started/c/mANrgH-7PMA
https://groups.google.com/g/liquid-galaxy/c/DwWQszEsRfM
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=194021
But none with a solution to my problem. I’ll add that I can’t use KMLNetworkLink to update my file with KMLs from the internet.

You're right, Thank you. I noticed it too. Plus, it's much cleaner and more adequate than what I suggested. Would you say that using a NetwokLink is the preferred way for the above purposes? Can you think of anything else?

You could use a NetworkLink and point to a local file. The link href doesn't have to be http/s, it can also be a relative or absolute path to a kml with live data
e.g. in "link.kml" have a NetworkLink pointing to "points.kml":
<NetworkLink>
  <Link>
    <href>points.kml</href>
    <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
    <refreshInterval>1</refreshInterval>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>


